# How to make horizontal bar chart scrollable for y axis with dynamic data in chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I have dynamic data which I need to show. But faced the problem with a big amount of data which needs to be displayed on Y axis. Is there is a way to make chart scrollable vertically to be able to see full displayed data the same as for small amount of data?

I'm using Angular, 14.1.0 PrimeNG 14.0.0, chart.js 3.8.2

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grjksv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63673329/2358409

Comment: @uminder yes it seems like what I'm trying to find but I can't reproduce it with my stackblitz. It somehow ignores overflow property and simply grows in height.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the chart is not scrollable out of the box.

But maybe you have already had a look but there is a plugin, Chart.js Hierarchical Scale Plugin, which can add a new categorical scale which mimics a hierarchical tree. Hopefully can help: https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-plugin-hierarchical

Comment: You could also use the Zoom plugin and its panning feature. https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom